# ESP8266 is reset when it receives the parameter related to sqlite3

Tags: c++, reset, esp8266

I wish you all a good day. Thank you in advance for your help.

When esp8266 sends a parameter from the web address line (related to sqlite3), it is reset, whether it does it or not.

example: 192.168.0.100/insert

screenshot example:

---

Unable to access this site. The link has been reset.
Try the following:

Checking your connection
Checking proxy and firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

---

But if the parameter about sqlite3 is not sent, it works normally.

example: 192.168.0.100/inline

screenshot example:

[image]

smartlockV1.ino

```
/*
 Name:      smartlockV1.ino
 Created:   31.03.2021 01:07:01
 Author:    IOT
*/

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
#include "DataAccessLayer.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vfs.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <FS.h>
extern "C" {
#include "user_interface.h"
}
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "Kentnet_CF5EA0"
#define STAPSK  "**********"
#endif

const char* ssid = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const int led = 2;

void handleInsert();
void handleSelect();


void handleRoot() {
    digitalWrite(led, 1);
    char temp[400];
    int sec = millis() / 1000;
    int min = sec / 60;
    int hr = min / 60;

    snprintf(temp, 400,
    "<html>\
      <head>\
        <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5'/>\
        <title>ESP8266 Demo</title>\
        <style>\
          body { background-color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; Color: #000088; }\
        </style>\
      </head>\
      <body>\
        <h1>Hello from ESP8266!</h1>\
        <p>Uptime: %02d:%02d:%02d</p>\
        <img src=\"/test.svg\" />\
      </body>\
    </html>",
    hr, min % 60, sec % 60
    );

    server.send(200, "text/html", temp);
    digitalWrite(led, 0);
}   


void handleNotFound() {
    digitalWrite(led, 1);
    String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
    message += "URI: ";
    message += server.uri();
    message += "\nMethod: ";
    message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
    message += "\nArguments: ";
    message += server.args();
    message += "\n";

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
        message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
    }

    server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
    digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void WiFiOff() {
    wifi_station_disconnect();
    wifi_set_opmode(NULL_MODE);
    wifi_set_sleep_type(MODEM_SLEEP_T);
    wifi_fpm_open();
    wifi_fpm_do_sleep(0xFFFFFFF);
}

File db_file_obj_1;

void setup() {   
    wdt_enable(WDTO_2S);    
    hw_wdt_disable();   

    system_update_cpu_freq(SYS_CPU_160MHZ);
    WiFiOff();
    
    vfs_set_spiffs_file_obj(&db_file_obj_1);
        
    Serial.println("Program started !");       

    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(led, 0);
    Serial.begin(74880);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    Serial.println("");

    // Wait for connection
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connected to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
        Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
    }

    server.on("/", handleRoot);        
    server.on("/test", handleTest);
    server.on("/insert", handleInsert);
    server.on("/Insert", handleInsert);
    server.on("/select", handleSelect);
    server.on("/Select", handleSelect);
    server.on("/inline", []() {
        server.send(200, "text/plain", "this works as well");
        });
    server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

    server.begin();
    Serial.println("HTTP server started");

    if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
        Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
    }  

}

// the loop function runs over and over again until power down or reset
// ====================================================================
void loop(void) {
    server.handleClient();
    MDNS.update();
}
// ====================================================================
void hw_wdt_disable() {
    *((volatile uint32_t*)0x60000900) &= ~(1); // Hardware WDT OFF
}

void hw_wdt_enable() {
    *((volatile uint32_t*)0x60000900) |= 1; // Hardware WDT ON
}

void handleInsert() {
    DataAccessLayerClass data;
    data.InsertValues();
}

void handleSelect() {
    DataAccessLayerClass data;
    data.SelectValues();    
}

void handleTest() {
    DataAccessLayerClass data;
    data.Test();
    server.send(200, "text/html", "function(DataAccessLayer.Test)");
}
```

DataAccessLayer.h

```
// 
// 
// 

#include "DataAccessLayer.h"

#include <vfs.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <FS.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
extern "C" {
#include "user_interface.h"
}
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>


sqlite3* db;
sqlite3_stmt* res;
int rec_count = 0;
const char* tail;

DataAccessLayerClass DataAccessLayer;

DataAccessLayerClass::DataAccessLayerClass()
{
   /* wdt_enable(WDTO_2S);

    hw_wdt_disable();*/

    Serial.begin(74880);

    Serial.println("Call function(init)");

    SystemStart();

    sqlite3_initialize();
    Serial.println("Init worked !");
}

void DataAccessLayerClass::init()
{    
}

void DataAccessLayerClass::hw_wdt_disable()
{
    *((volatile uint32_t*)0x60000900) &= ~(1); // Hardware WDT OFF
}

void DataAccessLayerClass::SystemStart()
{
    if (!SPIFFS.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Failed to mount file system");
        return;
    }    

    // list SPIFFS contents
    Dir dir = SPIFFS.openDir("/");
    while (dir.next()) {
        String fileName = dir.fileName();
        size_t fileSize = dir.fileSize();
        Serial.printf("FS File: %s, size: %ld\n", fileName.c_str(), (long)fileSize);
    }
    Serial.printf("\n");

    // remove existing file
    //SPIFFS.remove("/smartlockV1.db");
    
    //SPIFFS.remove("/test1.db"); 

    Serial.println("System Start worked !");
}

void DataAccessLayerClass::Test()
{
    Serial.println("function(DataAccessLayer.Test)");    
}

const char* data = "Callback function called";
static int callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName) {
    int i;
    Serial.printf("%s: ", (const char*)data);
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        Serial.printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }
    Serial.printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int db_open(const char* filename, sqlite3** db) {
    Serial.printf("function(db_open)\n");
    int rc = sqlite3_open(filename, db);
    if (rc) {
        Serial.printf("Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(*db));
        return rc;
    }
    else {
        Serial.printf("Opened database successfully\n");
    }
    return rc;
}

char* zErrMsg = 0;
int db_exec(sqlite3* db, const char* sql) {
    Serial.println(sql);
    long start = micros();
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        Serial.printf("SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    else {
        Serial.printf("Operation done successfully\n");
    }
    Serial.print(F("Time taken:"));
    Serial.println(micros() - start);
    return rc;
}

void DataAccessLayerClass::CreateTable()
{
    sqlite3* db;
    int rc;

    Serial.println("function(CreateTable)");

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbConfig (";
        sql += "Name TEXT, ";
        sql += "Phone TEXT, ";
        sql += "Email TEXT, ";
        sql += "Description TEXT, ";
        sql += "Date_Added TEXT";
        sql += ");";
    Serial.println("sql: " + sql);
    
    // Open databases        
    if (db_open("/FLASH/smartlockV1.db", &db)) return;

    rc = db_exec(db, sql.c_str());
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return;
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

void DataAccessLayerClass::InsertValues()
{
    sqlite3* db;
    int rc;

    Serial.println("function(InsertValues)");

    String sql = "INSERT INTO tbConfig VALUES ('Seza CALISKAN', '053201234567','hurol.keskinkilic@gmail.com','Oglu','21.11.2019-06:32');";       
        
    // Open databases        
    if (db_open("/FLASH/smartlockV1.db", &db)) return;            
    
    rc = db_exec(db, sql.c_str());
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return;
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

void DataAccessLayerClass::SelectValues()
{
    sqlite3* db;
    int rc;

    Serial.println("function(SelectValues)");

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbConfig";

    //// Open databases        
    if (db_open("/FLASH/smartlockV1.db", &db)) return;

    //rc = db_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM tbConfig");
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql.c_str(), 1000, &res, &tail);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return;
    }

    while (sqlite3_step(res) == SQLITE_ROW) {        
        Serial.print(sqlite3_column_int(res, 0)+' '); Serial.print(' ');
        Serial.print((const char*)sqlite3_column_text(res, 1)); Serial.print(' ');
        Serial.print((const char*)sqlite3_column_text(res, 2)); Serial.print(' ');
        Serial.print((const char*)sqlite3_column_text(res, 3)); Serial.print(' ');
        Serial.print((const char*)sqlite3_column_text(res, 4)); Serial.print(' ');
        Serial.print((const char*)sqlite3_column_text(res, 5)); 
        rec_count++;
        Serial.println();
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your program crashed. What does it print on serial?

Comment: do you not have to close `res`?